# MySQL ORDER BY appears to sort by hex and not alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, concatenation

I'm having a hard time with sorting in this query

```
SELECT 
    Strasse,
    CONCAT(CAST(Hausnummer AS CHAR), COALESCE(Buchstabe, '')),
    Name
FROM
    Adresse
WHERE
    GebietID = 'G20141205064123101'
ORDER BY
Strasse ASC , CONCAT(CAST(Hausnummer AS CHAR), COALESCE(Buchstabe, '')) ASC , Name ASC;
```

The concat is there to join a numerical value and a single character.
The resulting column appears to order basing on HEX values instead of the actual string values.

Is there a way to make it order alphabetically?

EDIT:
Here's some sample data:

```
'A20141205235645111', 'G20141205064123101', 'Amberg', 'Ahnherrnstraße', '6', NULL, 'Meier Johann Olga'
'A20141205235645361', 'G20141205064123101', 'Amberg', 'Ahnherrnstraße', '30', NULL, 'Stang Lidija Swetlana Waldemar'
'A20141215182839021', 'G20141205064123101', 'Amberg', 'Ahnherrnstraße', '6', NULL, 'MANFRED1'
```

And the result:

```
'Ahnherrnstraße', '30', 'Stang Lidija Swetlana Waldemar'
'Ahnherrnstraße', '6', 'MANFRED1'
'Ahnherrnstraße', '6', 'Meier Johann Olga'
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: @movildima please post the sample data **and** the result in the question

Comment: added sample data.

Comment: and the result?

Comment: oh, sorry , that's the result that I'm getting. I'll post the original table now.

Comment: if your question is answered, pls accept an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply

```
ORDER BY
Strasse, Hausnummer, Buchstabe, Name;
```

The result of the concat is a character. Thats why your ordering is lexical (30 before 6). If you order your columns separatly, Hausnummer is treated as number and sorted numerically. If two Hausnummers are the same, SQL will sort this entries after Buchstabe. NULL values will come first if you use ASC, which is the default by the way.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot that I can still sort by columns which I'm not selecting. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: This answer gives no explanation as to _why_ this ordering should work correctly.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: thanks, i edited my comment to give the missing explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is specualtive, but I think that you want to sort by street numbers and their names, but you are getting a lexigraphical order which doesn't agree numerically.  One option would be to add an extra level to the sort which splits street names from their numbers, i.e.

```
ORDER BY Strasse,
         Hausnummer,
         COALESCE(Buchstabe, ''),
         Name
```

Note that in MySQL the default sort order is ascending, so you don't need to use `ASC` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have the family `Stang` residing at, maybe, `30B Ahnherrnstraße`.  And the family `Meier` at, maybe, `30 Ahnherrnstraße`

Then you'll have someone else at `8 Ahnherrnstraße`, for example.

I suppose you want to show these in the following order.

```
 8 Ahnherrnstraße
 30 Ahnherrnstraße
 30B Ahnherrnstraße
```

To do that correctly, you cannot cast `Hausnummer` as a character string in your `ORDER BY` clause, or it will sort lexically rather than numerically.

You'll want `ORDER BY Strasse, Hausnummer, COALESCE(Buchstabe,' '), Name`

Why `COALESCE(Buchstabe,' ')` ? You want to be sure your items with a NULL Buchstabe come first, before the others.  space is the first character. If you want them last, use `COALESCE(Buchstabe,'~')`.